# MySQL query support please

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table (pity no pictures for first post)

```
Team_id,entry_date, entry_time,gridref
"20","2011-12-14","10:21:00","496218"
"20","2011-12-14","10:43:02","349217"
"21","2011-12-14","10:48:00","351213"
"22","2011-12-14","11:58:00","327216"
"22","2011-12-14","11:21:00","328214"
"23","2011-12-14","11:33:00","351210"
"23","2011-12-14","10:42:11","350210"
"23","2011-12-14","11:11:00","350208"
"24","2011-12-14","10:39:00","329209"
"24","2011-12-14","11:40:00","328211"
"27","2011-12-14","11:04:31","344226"
"29","2011-12-14","11:32:58","328208"
```

The SQL to get this is

```
SELECT team_id, entry_date, entry_time, gridref 
FROM `tlog` 
WHERE gridref != '' 
    AND team_id != 0 
    AND (entry_date = (SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM `tlog`)) 
ORDER BY `tlog`.`team_id` ASC
```

There is quite a bit of data over several days and entries for each team could be entrered in any order and not neccessarily at the time of the info (if could be entered a day later).  I had problems with users trying to enter yyyy-mm-mm hh:mm format as they missed spaces and characters.  So seperate date and time enties has fixed that problem.

There are also entries that don't relate to a team or don't have a gridref.  However there is an entry_date and entry_time for every entry.  MySQL format for entry_date is DATE and entry_time is TIME.

I'm having a *senior* moment trying to get the last entry for each team. Could someone throw me a bone to chew on please.

Comment: Maybe need to use `GROUP BY tlog.team_id` ?

Comment: Try using `SELECT * FROM tlog WHERE gridref != '' AND team_id != 0 ORDER BY tlog.entry_date DESC GROUP BY tlog.team_id;`

Comment: What do you mean by _"get the last entry for each team"_?

Comment: If you have a look at the snip of data above you'll notice that each team_id appears at least twice.  The above data is only a snip of all the data over several days.  The last date/time entry is the one I want so I can return the team_id and gridref.  (I use this gridref to plot on google maps where the last position of each team was).

Comment: I ended up working with [link]select t.team_id, t.entry_date, t.entry_time, t.gridref  
from tlog t  
inner join (select t2.team_id, med.ed, max(entry_time) et from tlog t2  
                 inner join (select team_id, max(entry_date) ed from tlog where team_id > 0 group by team_id) med on med.team_id = t2.team_id and med.ed = t2.entry_date WHERE gridref <> '' group by t2.team_id, med.ed) met on met.team_id = t.team_id and met.ed = t.entry_date and met.et = t.entry_time[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the max date per team then the max time for that date per team in sub queries then join in the outer query on team id, date and time:

```
select t.teamid, t.entryDate, t.entryTime, t.gridRef  
from tlog t  
inner join (select t2.teamid, med.ed, max(entryTime) et from tlog t2  
                 inner join (select teamid, max(entryDate) ed from tlog where teamid > 0 and gridRef <> '' group by teamid) med on med.teamid = t2.teamid and med.ed = t2.entryDate group by t2.teamid, med.ed) met on met.teamid = t.teamid and met.ed = t.entryDate and met.et = t.entryTime
```

To try to build queries such as this just go through the logical steps ie firstly you need the latest date per team - write a query that achieves that. Then you need the latest time for each of those dates. Then find the details that match those. Use temporary tables if it helps to make it clearer.

Note you can't just have a single sub query max(entryDate) and max(entryTime) because the latest time is not necessarily on the latest date.

If supported by MySQL and you want only a single subquery you need to concatenate the date and time together eg

```
max(entryDate + ' ' + entryTime)
```

Obviously for this you may need to convert to data types that support concatenation

Comment: Hmmm, tried that one got the same results as I get with my other one.  I'll keep playing and see how I go.

Comment: Aaahhh, now we're getting close but there are records that don't have a team_id or don't have a gridref.  So I want to filter out all records that don't have team_id or the gridref is empty and only show the last records for each that has a team_id > 0 and the gridref is not blank (!='').

Comment: So you just add those conditions (and any others) to the innermost loop so they're excluded from the data set as early as possible. The syntax of these checks varies by data type and database so you may need to tweak for your implementation. I've shown SQL server.

Comment: Okay this last one is returning all of the last records but not all have gridrefs.  In other words it is returning blank gridrefs on some records.  Thanks by the way for all your efforts so far.

Comment: Like I said, you may need to change the where clause depending on data type and database - this works for me. You need to change the checks based on your version. Just do a simple select from tlog and work out how to exclude the rows you don't want eg check for null/empty string. Then update the inner query here with the same conditions

Comment: yep got it. I'll give it go tomorrow.  Yhanks for you're help.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks KAJ. I ended up working with 
`select t.team_id, t.entry_date, t.entry_time, t.gridref  
from tlog t  
inner join (select t2.team_id, med.ed, max(entry_time) et from tlog t2  
                 inner join (select team_id, max(entry_date) ed from tlog where team_id > 0 group by team_id) med on med.team_id = t2.team_id and med.ed = t2.entry_date WHERE gridref <> '' group by t2.team_id, med.ed) met on met.team_id = t.team_id and met.ed = t.entry_date and met.et = t.entry_time'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM `tlog` WHERE gridref != '' AND team_id != 0 GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: This won't give the last entry by time though.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the date and time in a datetime or int (timestamp) column. Yes, it can be done like this, but you gain no profit, but problems instead.

Fix this at the view layer. If the user makes mistakes while typing in dates, take a javascript calendar control and let them select dates and times.

If that isn't possible, then use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and some string concatenation to parse the input.

Comment: The problem with a timestamp is that the entries can be entered out of order and could be entered 2-3 days later so sorting by timestamp won't work in this case.

Comment: @user1227400 the timestamp column doesn't have to be filled with the _current_ timestamp.

Comment: Yeah I know, but for certain administrial reasons, I can't use a combined date/time field.